# Ensure in many-to-many relationship at least one relationship is primary

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the bad title, if you can think of a better one, let me know.

Many-to-many relationship using tables.

- Product
- ProductCategory
- Category

In the ProductCategory table i have boolean column primarycategory

Each product must have a primary category.

### I want to find all products in my database which don't have a primarycategory.

Comment: if you're asking for a query we'll need the table definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: I have assumed field names in tables other than the one you specified.**

This should return a distinct list of product IDs that have no primary category. Bit fields in SQL server are numeric, so you can give them to the `max()` function.

```
select
   pc.product
from
   ProductCategory pc
group by
   pc.product
having
   max(pc.primarycategory) = 0
```

The above query assumes that all products have at least one category. If not, try the following:

```
select
   pc.product
from
   Product p
   left join
   ProductCategory pc on p.id = pc.product
group by
   pc.product
having
   max(isnull(pc.primarycategory, 0)) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming true = value 1, try this:

```
  Select Product From Product p
  Where Not Exists (Select * From ProductCategory
                    Where Product = p.Product  
                       And primarycategory = 1 )
```

but if you have control over this database, Move the PrimaryCategory column to the Products table, (and populate it with the category identifier itself, not a boolean), that is where this belongs in a properly normalized schema...